# How to get access to the REST endpoints based on roles that are coming from payload claim JWT

Tags: java, spring, rest, jwt

I am trying to authenticate myself based on roles that I get in my claims. Basically I want to be able to connect to my application only if the specific roles are part of the claim

Dependencies :

```xml
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.4</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.4</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.4</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This is my security class :

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class SecurityOAuth2Config {
    
      private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SecurityOAuth2Config.class);
    
      @Bean
      public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http
          .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
          .headers(header -> header.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
          .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
          .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
          .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/actuator/health")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/actuator/info")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
            // Invoked internally inside the kubernetes cluster
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/internal/api/**")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/**"))
            .hasAnyRole("User1", "Admin3","TestDataUploader")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
          )
          .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(jwtConfigurer ->
            jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())));
    
    
        return http.getOrBuild();
      }
    
      @Bean
      public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        var grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("role");
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");
        var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
      }
    
      @Bean
      public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
          Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
          LOGGER.info("AUTHORITIES " +  authorities);
          authorities.forEach(authority -> {
            if (authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority oidcAuth) {
              oidcAuth.getUserInfo().getClaimAsStringList("role").forEach(
                role -> mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("" + role)));
            }
          });
          mappedAuthorities.addAll(authorities);
    
          return mappedAuthorities;
        };
      }
    }
```

I all the time get unauthorized

Bearer token example

```json
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1699881658,
  "iss": "https://id.test.io/",
  "upn": "Jon",
  "role": [
    "Admin",
    "Approve"
  ]
}
```

Controller endpoint example

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ApplicationListController {
      private ServiceApp serviceApp;

     @GetMapping("/app")
     public Collection<Response> getApplications() {
       return serviceApp.loadResponse();
    }
   }
```

Application yaml file

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://id.test.io/
          jwk-set-uri: https://id.test.io/.well-known/jwks.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove remove  your `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` bean, it duplicates what you already configured on the `JwtAuthenticationConverter`.

When using `.hasAnyRole("User1", "Admin3","TestDataUploader")`, you expect the authentication to contain one of `ROLE_User1`, `ROLE_Admin3` or `ROLE_TestDataUploader` authorities, but you map the `"role": [ "Admin", "Approve" ]` claim without a prefix => authorities are `Admin` and  `Approve` => **no match  because of missing `ROLE_` prefix and because expected role is `Admin3`** (not `Admin` as contained in your claims). Three options:

- change access control rule to `.hasAnyAuthority("User1", "Admin","TestDataUploader")`
- change access control rule to `.hasAnyRole("User1", "Admin","TestDataUploader")` and update your `JwtAuthenticationConverter` with `grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");`
- change the role name on your authorization server from `Admin` to `ROLE_Admin3` (the claim in the token would be `"role": [ "ROLE_Admin3", "ROLE_Approve" ]`)

##### Solution 1: with only "official" Boot starters

`spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` is enough, you don't need to explicitly depend on `spring-boot-starter-security`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Update your Java conf as follow (implementation of the second bullet point above):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityOAuth2Config {
    
      private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SecurityOAuth2Config.class);
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter) throws Exception {
        http
          .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
          .headers(header -> header.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
          .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
          .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
          .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/actuator/health")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/actuator/info")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
            // Invoked internally inside the kubernetes cluster
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/internal/api/**")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/**"))
            .hasAnyRole("Admin", "User1", "TestDataUploader")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
          )
          .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(jwtConfigurer ->
            jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)));

        return http.getOrBuild();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        var grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("role");
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
        var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
}
```

Keep the same properties (optionally remove `jwk-set-uri` which is most probably redundant in your case):

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://id.test.io/
          # jwk-set-uri is not needed when 
          # - the resource server can reach .well-known/openid-configuration using issuer-uri
          # - the iss claim in access tokens is exactly the value of issuer-uri (including case and trailing slash if any)
          # jwk-set-uri: https://id.test.io/.well-known/jwks.json
```

##### Solution 2: using [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/#ease-openid-configuration--tests-in-spring-boot-3) & method security

This would probably make your life easier.

One more dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.*` with the following:

```yaml
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: https://id.test.io/
          username-claim: upn
          authorities:
          - path: $.roles
            prefix: ROLE_
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          - /actuator/health
          - /actuator/info
          - /h2-console/**
          - /internal/api/**
          cors:
```

Clear your Java security conf and add `@EnableMethodSecurity`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityOAuth2Config {
}
```

Yes, that simple, the stateless resource server filter-chain is created for you,  based on the application properties above.

Your controller becomes (mind the `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Admin', 'User1', 'TestDataUploader')")`):

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationListController {
    private ServiceApp serviceApp;

    @GetMapping("/app")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Admin', 'User1', 'TestDataUploader')")
    public Collection<Response> getApplications() {
        return serviceApp.loadResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: that is a great answer. I kind have to stick with spring security. I am just wondering if actually for the first solution if is something more needed in application yaml maybe ? I updated the question with what I added so far

Comment: My starter uses Spring Security. It does no more than helping to configure it. Follow [the link to my repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/#ease-openid-configuration--tests-in-spring-boot-3), you'll find pros / cons and explanation of how it works (plus the source, of course)

Comment: No, with just `spring-boot-stater-oauth2-resource-server`, you don't need more properties than those you already have (not much is configurable for OAuth2 with official starter). As stated in the comment of the yaml in my answer, replace it only if using `spring-addons-starter-oidc` (reason is that you can't configure static multi-tenancy with Boot official properties syntax but my starter allows it). Just try exactly what I answered, both should work (without my starter, updated Java conf and same properties; or with my starter, cleared Java security conf and replaced properties)

Comment: if I remove the     
oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://id.test.io/
          jwk-set-uri: https://id.test.io/.well-known/jwks.json

and use your first approach I am getting soething like this Using generated security password: 761d965a-8738-4c2d-8e76-91352247d458  remove before production

Comment: Sure you are. You can't mix the solutions. The "official" starter doesn't know about "add-ons" properties. Read my comment or answer again, **these are two distinct solutions**

Comment: Unfortunately is not possible to use the add on due to some restrictions. I am allowed to use only the "official" implementaiton. However I can not make the endpoint to not get unauthorized. DO you think you can help with a solution that includes also a valid token ? Maybe I am misconfiguring something. Thank you very much for your support. In any other context I would use add ons but now I need to find a solution without

Comment: I gave it: it is labeled solution 1 in the answer. I you can't get it working because of other misconfigurations than those I already pointed, then you figured out why it can be safer to use my starter too configure `spring-security` for you when you're not quite sure of what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

Give Access Ur Controller with `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('role')")`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationListController {
    private ServiceApp serviceApp;

    @GetMapping("/app")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('Admin','Approve')")
    public Collection<Response> getApplications() {
        return serviceApp.loadResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: in my case now `ROLE` Not Dynamic, im using dynamic with `PERMISSION`