# ADFS JWT integration with 2 issuers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, adfs

I am trying to authorize the application with adfs. FOr many days I though the problem is with the authorization itself

[How to get access to the REST endpoints based on roles that are coming from payload claim JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474707/how-to-get-access-to-the-rest-endpoints-based-on-roles-that-are-coming-from-payl/77475648?noredirect=1#comment136618811_77475648)

However I discovered that in adfs you have an issuer path but also an access_token_issuer. After analyzing the calls for adfs I relizaed that both the issuer and access token issuer needs to be somehow specified. Without the issuer there is no access to the wellknown and without the access-token-issuer the token is not checked agains the correct issuer. Did anyone expeienced this and has any clue how to modify the JWT decoder to use the issuer and access-token issuer as well.

```
  issueruri = adfs uri that has also the well known config
   accessIssuerUri = the one that I receive in the claims in the iss

  @Bean
 public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
     return NimbusJwtDecoder.withIssuerLocation(this.issuerUri).build();
  }
```

The complete code is also in the question that I added as a link.

openId config contains something like this

```
{
    "issuer": "https://base-url/adfs",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://base-url/adfs/oauth2/authorize/",
    "token_endpoint": "https://base-url/adfs/oauth2/token/",
    "jwks_uri": "https://base-url/adfs/discovery/keys",
....
    "access_token_issuer": "http://base-url/adfs/services/trust",
 .....
}
```

is the issuer or access_token_issuer the one that I have to add in my decoder and also in appllication properties

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: 
          jwk-set-uri:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `jwk-set-uri` in yaml with the value of `jwks_uri` in your openid-configuration and either:

- remove `issuer-uri` from yaml (disables `iss` claim validation)
- set `issuer-uri` with **exactly** the value of `iss` claim in your access tokens (case and trailing slash, if any, are important)

Spring Security uses `issuer-uri` for two things if present:

- **if `jwk-set-uri` property is missing** (and only in that case) , try to fetch OpenID configuration from well known path and try to get `jwks_uri` from it
- add an issuer validator to the JWT decoder (checks that the `iss` claim in access tokens is exactly the value you provide as `issuer-uri`)

Issuer validation is optional (as well as audience one). Only required validation is token signature, reason for Spring Security needing the JWK-set (either provided explicitly or infered from issuer URI).

Comment: I have another question, how did you setup trustore location / password ? :)

Comment: trustore for what?

Comment: I mean I already have a trustore mounted for ADFS and I need to specify  it in my resources (location) so when I call adfs the be able to call it securely (is there something like spriing.security.ouath.trustorelocation  )

Comment: The keys to secure the communication channel and those used to sign tokens are different things. My OIDC authorization servers are using good old SSL certificates from letsencrypt for https.